# How can I easily find out what has changed in an app after an auto update notification?

Tags: applications, updates, notifications, application-autoupdate

When I get a notification about an app update I often wonder what changed in this update. Is there a quick & easy way to find out? (No typing.)

*Note: This is with auto-update enabled, when the update is already installed.*

Comment: Tapping the notification usually brings up teh market link. You will find the changelog for the app there, if developer is diligent enough. Otherwise, you'll need google for answers

Comment: @forums Mind placing this as an answer? Looks valid enough for me (you might add a few details, like the tab to look for).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know the changes made in the app after the update then simply follow this steps.

1. Slide down the [notification bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WhEk.png)
2. Tap the [update notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E972T.png).
   This will bring up the market link (unless you set the app to auto-update which will open up the app and not the market link because the update is already installed).
3. Once you're in, search for the app in question, select it, and there you will find the changelog like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmG4c.png).

Notice that you cannot do this if **auto-update** is enabled. You must open the Play Store, tap **Menu** (three dots in upper right of screen), and select **My Apps**. From there, do **step 3**.

Take note that not all developers post their changes in the market. For that you will need to google for the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I've got auto-update enabled, still useful to be reminded that you can find it through My Apps.